# How to remove the word "msc" from the message sequence chart using msc package?

Tags: macros

I am using the `msc` package for creating/drawing message sequence chart. Is there any way to remove the word "msc" from the message sequence chart which appears by default along with the title of the chart? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't have time for a proper answer now, but try adding `\renewcommand{\msckeyword}{}` after `\usepackage{msc}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

As karlkoeller says in the comments, this is documented in [`msc`s reference manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/msc/refman.pdf). The text added in the environments are stored in the macros `\msckeyword`, `\hmsckeyword` and `\mscdockeyword` for the environments `msc`, `hmsc` and `mscdoc` respectively.

By redefining these with

```
\renewcommand\msckeyword{<replacement text>} 
\renewcommand\hmsckeyword{<replacement text>}
\renewcommand\mscdockeyword{<replacement text>}
```

you can remove the keywords, which by default are  **msc**, **hmsc** and **mscdoc**, from the graphics. Of course, if you only use the `msc` environment you don't need to redefine the other two.

Complete code example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{msc}
\renewcommand\msckeyword{} 
\renewcommand\hmsckeyword{}
\renewcommand\mscdockeyword{}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{Example}
\declinst{usr}{User}{}
\end{msc}
\begin{hmsc}{High level}(0,0)(4,3.7)
\hmscstartsymbol{s}(2,1)
\end{hmsc}
\begin{mscdoc}{My declarations}%
(0,0)(4,3.7)
\reference{a}(1,1)
\end{mscdoc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not blind... You have to read the [Reference Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/msc/refman.pdf) at page 9 and not the User Manual.

Comment: @karlkoeller Oh, there's a reference as well. I just did `texdoc msc` and browsed that. Thanks, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Torbjorn for the quick answer. However I'm getting a peculiar error saying \msckeyword undefined when I run my code with the code suggested by you in pdfLaTeX. If I run it in LaTeX=>DVI then there is no error but I'm not able to see the dvi output either. I'm not able to figureout the problem.

Comment: @SanjaySingh `msc` uses `pstricks` which again uses PostScript to draw the diagrams. `pdflatex` cannot generate PostScript graphics. You can compile directly to PDF with `xelatex`, or convert the DVI first to PostScript with `dvips` and from PS to PDF with `ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version¹ of `msc` there is a command `msc keyword` for that:

```
\begin{msc}[msc keyword=]{Title}
\end{msc}
```

¹ Currently *Version A2.0, last update June 3, 2014*

Comment: thanks brother !!