# How to get rid of "msc" text on image using LaTeX and Tikz (PsTricks) package?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, msc

I have a tex code, where I try to generate some simple flows. I compile it like this:

1. `latex toc.tex`
2. `dvips toc.dvi`
3. `pstopdf toc.ps`

The output I got:

[image]

And I would like to get rid of the `msc IJS_{NK, dec/enc}` text in the upper left corner, or at least move it somewhere else.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-fct}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{msc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\center
\resizebox{12cm}{!} {
\begin{msc}{$IJS_{NK, dec/enc}$}
\small
\setlength{\instwidth}{1.7 cm}
\setlength{\instdist}{4.3 cm}
\setlength{\bottomfootdist}{0.2 cm}
%\setlength{\instwidth}{2 cm}
%\setlength{\instdist}{3.75 cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{1.2 cm}
\setlength{\topheaddist}{0.5 cm}
\instfoot

\declinst{I}{\scriptsize new node}{$I$} 
\declinst{R}{\scriptsize neighbour node}{$R$}
\declinst{J1k-1}{\scriptsize intermediate nodes}{$J_{1:k-1}$}
\declinst{Jk}{\scriptsize \:\: intermediate node}{$J_{k}$}
\declinst{S}{\scriptsize Sink}{$S$}

% left to right messages
\mess{$m_1 = \{n_I, I, R\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)}$}{I}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{R}{J1k-1}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_{k-1}}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{J1k-1}{Jk}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_k}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{Jk}{S}
\nextlevel

% right to left messages
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_k}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{S}{Jk}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_{J_{k-1}}, ..., n_{J_1}, n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{Jk}{J1k-1}
\nextlevel
\mess{$\{n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{J1k-1}{R}
\nextlevel
\mess{$m_3$}{R}{I}
%\nextlevel
\end{msc}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{11.5 cm}
$m_2 = \{pk(I), \{n_I, I, R, S\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)}\}_{K_{DH}(R,S)}$\\
$m_3 = \{K(R,I), \{n_I, I, R, S\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)} \}_{pk(I)}$
\end{minipage} 
}
\caption{$IJS_{NK, dec/enc}$: Proof by Induction.}
\label{figure : IJS-NK-dec-enc Induction}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

**SOLVED!**

It was enough to add

```
\renewcommand\msckeyword{} 
\renewcommand\hmsckeyword{}
\renewcommand\mscdockeyword{}
```

before `\begin{document}` and .. done! This answear helped me: [How to remove the word "msc" from the message sequence chart using msc package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162491/how-to-remove-the-word-msc-from-the-message-sequence-chart-using-msc-package).

[image]

Comment: I don't know how this connects to TikZ. msc uses PsTricks

Comment: @percusse: Sorry for this, my bad. I just started with `TikZ`, it was not very clear to me.

Comment: No problem. It was a bit too short for a comment on my side. Since I don't know anything about msc just placed a remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `\setmsckeyword{}` and call `msc` with an empty argument.

I also reordered the input: the settings to the `msc` parameters are better done outside the box to be resized. I made both boxes as wide as `\textwidth`; change it to an explicit dimension or to a factor of `\textwidth` such as `0.8\textwidth`.

Use `\centering` and not `\center`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{msc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!htp]
\centering

\setmsckeyword{}% remove the word msc
\setlength{\instwidth}{1.7 cm}
\setlength{\instdist}{4.3 cm}
\setlength{\bottomfootdist}{0.2 cm}
%\setlength{\instwidth}{2 cm}
%\setlength{\instdist}{3.75 cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{1.2 cm}
\setlength{\topheaddist}{0.5 cm}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% <-- don't forget this %
  \begin{msc}{}
  \declinst{I}{\scriptsize new node}{$I$} 
  \declinst{R}{\scriptsize neighbour node}{$R$}
  \declinst{J1k-1}{\scriptsize intermediate nodes}{$J_{1:k-1}$}
  \declinst{Jk}{\scriptsize \:\: intermediate node}{$J_{k}$}
  \declinst{S}{\scriptsize Sink}{$S$}
  %
  % left to right messages
  \mess{$m_1 = \{n_I, I, R\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)}$}{I}{R}
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$\{n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{R}{J1k-1}
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$\{n_{J_{k-1}}, \dots, n_{J_1}, n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{J1k-1}{Jk}
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$\{n_{J_k}, \dots, n_{J_1}, n_R, m_1\}_{NK}$}{Jk}{S}
  \nextlevel
  %
  % right to left messages
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$\{n_{J_k}, \dots, n_{J_1}, n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{S}{Jk}
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$\{n_{J_{k-1}}, \dots, n_{J_1}, n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{Jk}{J1k-1}
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$\{n_R, m_2\}_{NK}$}{J1k-1}{R}
  \nextlevel
  \mess{$m_3$}{R}{I}
  %\nextlevel
  \end{msc}% <-- don't forget this %
}

\fbox{% <-- don't forget this %
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  $m_2 = \{pk(I), \{n_I, I, R, S\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)}\}_{K_{DH}(R,S)}$\\
  $m_3 = \{K(R,I), \{n_I, I, R, S\}_{K_{DH}(I,S)} \}_{pk(I)}$
  \end{minipage}% <-- don't forget this %
}

\caption{$IJS_{NK, \mathrm{dec}/\mathrm{enc}}$: Proof by Induction.}
\label{figure : IJS-NK-dec-enc Induction}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gives me `! Package babel Error: Unknown language english. Either you have ...` while compiling with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @yak Remove the `.aux` file and retry. I didn't include `babel` in the example because it's not essential for it (likewise for the others I omitted); this way the code is more useful for future readers who will only see the necessary packages, Oh, and you *can't* use `pdflatex` with `msc`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's all ok now :) It's good to know that I cant use `pdflatex` with `msc` - didnt know this. Cheers